# Exit program with saving using batch

Tags: excel, batch-file, xlsx

I m trying to open and exit the xlsx file with saving using batch file. If the opens- works ok, but there are some problems with exit- because I cant save new stuff in file using taskkill command.

```
 PROGRAMM=2.xlsx
 Start 2.xlsx
 Sleep 30
 TASKKILL /F /IM EXCEL*
```

Are there any choices to exit from xlsx with saving using batch?

Comment: `taskkill` doesn't send a "exit request" to the application, it just - uhm - kills it. You need a way to communicate with the application (excel in your case). Batch doesn't provide a (native) way to do this. I think, `vbs` can, but I`m not sure.

Comment: Using batch no. Do google examples with creating object using jscript or vbscript - they have the same possibilities and just different syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/f
```

says to force a termination. Without it it's like clicking the close button, it's a request to the program to terminate, the program is free to ignore it.

With `/f` the program is not asked to close but is terminated by windows. The program doesn't even know what's happening.

```
Set xlBook = GetObject("C:\Users\User\Documents\Super.xls")
xlBook.Save
```

Above vbs script opens and save a document.